# Fired for inappropriate behavior. How to handle resume and future jobs?

Tags: resume, united-states, human-resources, termination

So a month ago I was forced from my job for inappropriate behavior. I am still claiming that it didnt happen... so essentially someone I was working training at the time was placing claims about me into HR. They started off as dumb like she texted me for help then I texted her back with instructions she filed an hr complaint. I needed to know someones salary (our new hr guy) he told me a high number so I told him I would have to confirm that. She reported it and it was thrown out. One day she 'adjusted her bra strap' but instead of moving it from outside her clothes she dragged her top to the side exposing her bra and breast I ask her what she was doing because i was in the middle of showing her something she asked me to she answered adjusting herself i pretended it didnt happen and continued to show her what she needed. I then was in hr when I found out about the prior complaints and she said I called her boobs 'jiggly'. I denied it ever happen and followed instructions to

A) always have my future interactions with the associate documented 
B) always have someone trustworthy around when we spoke

I was told that it was her word against mine so I no longer worried. The next day she kept trying to get me one on one and I refused and also made a complaint.

I then was dragged into a room and was told some manager (I dont remember one being around at the time) backed her story and was fired.

So now on my future resumes what is the best way to handle this? And going forward, what is the best way to handle associates that are passive aggressive?

Comment: First of all, I would demand any and all evidence they have against you and fight it. Also your location might be important here, since laws and hiring behaviors differ greatly between countries.

Comment: She'd be explaining what happened to my wif if it was me.

Comment: I am currently located in PA which is a right to work state. The HR guy was also termed after me so I have no one to request the information from

Comment: The work environment was toxic I was doing 3 jobs working 70 hr weeks. The term  rate is generally after four months. I accepted it and just want to move on in life.

Comment: How long were you there? If people normally only last 4 months, can you just omit it from your resume? Maybe say you were travelling, caring for a sick relative, training, whetever?

Comment: It was 4 months but I gained a lot of good experience and the salary was 75k so I want that as a start for my next position

Comment: @user468190 Do you know why the HR guy was termed

Comment: @Twyxz I am unaware. It was a chaotic environment and he seemed unable to handle small things.

Comment: @Wilbert I've never worried about that, and I've had one complaint about my behavior which still leaves me wondering, but had no effect on my job.  In this case, it wasn't the complaint that got the guy fired, but the manager who stepped in, for unknown reasons.

Comment: @Wilbert I disagree that this advice is necessary or wise. If the OP's description is correct then the other employee (plus an alleged witness in management!) is simply lying, which would still be possible even if they never met one-on-one. Further, being unable to interact with a whole swathe of employees individually could be a significant barrier to getting work done-- I would probably not tolerate much disruption to work for an employee with such a policy. Finally, such a course might be advisable if frivolous complaints are very common, which I'm not sure is the case.

Comment: (continued) In the case of a coworker who is known to file lots of frivolous complaints with HR (as is the case described by the OP here) I might adjust my position. But all women, all the time? Wild overkill, with questionable effectiveness even then.

Comment: @user468190 Can you give a little bit more detail about some of the actual complaints? The first one you describe, about the text messages, doesn't make any sense to me (she can't have complained that you sent a reply to her text, right? How could HR take such a complaint seriously?). Was that one also thrown out?

Comment: @Upper_Case Yes it was thrown out once the text messages were provided to HR. As all of them dealt with work. She was making claims until one essentially stuck.

Comment: Please consider reviewing future questions for readability and formatting. I realize this question is closed because it's been answered, but it was incredibly hard to read.

Answer (score 8):

Taking the information given in your comments into account, simply don't mention the HR problem in any resume or interview if not explicitely prompted for it.

You write that the environment was toxic and chaotic and "The term rate is generally after four months." That is enough explanation for a short employement period in an interview. Don't put the focus on you (terminated due to HR complains) but on the company (toxic environment, average termination time about 4 months).

Now to the second question:

> And going forward in future jobs what is the best way to handle associates that are passive aggressive?

The good news is that in a good working environment you usually have much less of these problems, but since they depend on the personality of the employees you are never quite safe from them.

- Make a good first impression for everyone. Smile, greet your celleagues and be friendly. That way you defuse trouble before it arises and you make yourself less of a target (who would want to target the nice guy?).
- If possible, don't interact with troublemakers. They usually complain about anyone and anything, so you should have no problem spotting them.
- If you must interact with them, stay professional, neutral and objective. Don't give them the impression you're flirting (too friendly) or targeting them (too unfriendly).
- If they complain about you, try to defuse by **asking them personally what you've done wrong**. Either you can explain that you didn't mean anything bad or they see that you're trying to be better.
- If things escalate and HR gets involved, don't accept any blame for any actions you didn't do. Recall the events as objectively as possible. Try to create a paper trail and have witnesses around.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was sleeping in my office to get worked done so I have been left with a strong feeling of betrayal from the company. I'm just unsure how to go about and dont want to be in the same position again.

Comment: Resumes are only for describing where you worked, what you did, what skills you developed and used, and any accomplishments you may want to highlight. You should not say anything about the culture or other difficulties at any of your employers. Resumes should not include reasons for leaving. Some application forms ask your reason for leaving a previous employer. You only need to say that you decided to seek other employment. Don’t bring any of it up in an interview unless specifically asked. Even then, your first response to such a question should be similar: it was time for a change.